# I am on Tier2 visa in UK (from India) with my family. We want to visit France and other European Coutries. What should we do for visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, france, indian-citizens

I work for a University in the UK (Northern Ireland) as a member of Research Staff on a Tier2 visa (2 years multiple entry). I am from India, and hold Indian Citizenship. I also have my wife and daughter with me in Northern Ireland. We have just completed my 1st year. We want to travel other European countries during our time here but we are not sure if we need any kind of special visa for that. We are planning to visit Paris this summer. Could you please let me know where I can get right information for this and what should I do.

Comment: Ireland isn't in UK. Northern Ireland is in UK. If you are in NI then apply for a Schengen visa.

Comment: @DumbCoder “Ireland” is complex. The Republic of Ireland and the UK each control part of it and agreed that people from Northern Ireland are entitled to consider themselves Irish, British or both. Northern Ireland is definitely Ireland too, in several ways.

Comment: Skamila, can you please clarify that you are in Northern Ireland? Presumably Belfast University?

Comment: @DumbCoder, if the OP were in the ROI he wouldn't have a T2 because the ROI does something else.  Ipso facto, Northern Ireland.

Comment: @DJClayworth. By "Belfast University", do you mean Queen's University Belfast, commonly (throughout the island) known as "Queen's".

Comment: @TRiG Oops, yes I do.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you need a visa depends on your citizenship (the rules are more-or-less the same as they would be if you would still reside outside the European Union) and since you are an Indian citizen, it means you need a Schengen visa for a short visit.

You will have to apply for it from the relevant consulate in the UK. For a visit to France, that would be the French Consulate General in London (Edinburgh is close as well but Northern Ireland is covered by the Consulate General in London). You will have to go through TLSContact, an outsourcing firm, [all info are on the website](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/Visas-21435).

Being a UK Tier 2 visa holder should help a bit as it makes you less of a risk in the eyes of the consulate but it does not entitle you to visit France.